# How to safely uninstall (an incorrectly installed) Numpy on Mac OS-Monterrey?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, numpy, pip

Because I didn't know better, I have installed Numpy directly on my MacOS-Monterrey system outside a virtual environment, and now I want to safely uninstall Numpy without causing any harm to my system. However; I have realized from `Pip3 freeze` that other packages in my system, such as altgraph, future, macholib, and six, depend on Numpy.
But by removing those before uninstalling Numpy, I'm afraid I'd could create a domino effect that could break other packages creating further issues. Long story short, how can I safely uninstall numpy without affecting other functions?

Any help would be much appreciate,

Thanks

E

So far I'm not sure if I could simply run

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

Comment: You could just leave it there… Anyway, if it was installed with `pip install numpy` you can uninstall it safely.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I indeed installed numpy with "pip3 install numpy"